# Is it right to call (label) a method returning a task as async

Tags: c#, async-await

I have methods provided by the database driver that pushes a value to db (both async and non-async) like so,

`pushToDBAsync();` and `pushToDB();`

So I created a wrapper method for the driver methods for my own implementation shown below. Is this correct? and also Is it right to call this an async method?

```
public Task<bool> pushToDBAsync(.....)
{
    return _database.pushToDBAsync(.....);
}
```

Comment: You mean `return await _database.pushToDBAsync(.....);`?

Comment: Is your question "Should I name methods returning a Task with a name ending in Async?"

Comment: @Sweeper `async/await` is unnecessary in that particular method

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes That was my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you want to use your method as a pushToDBAsync(); so you follow below code for method syntax.

```
public Async Task<bool> pushToDBAsync(.....)
{
return await _database.pushToDBAsync(.....);
}
```

*If you want to use your method as a pushToDB(); So you follow below code for method syntax.

```
public Task<bool> pushToDBAsync(.....)
{
  return _database.pushToDBAsync(.....);
 // Return same but execution time more compare than Async method.
 }
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between these two versions of the method, other than that the first will have *slightly* more overhead due to being rewritten into a state machine. Both returns a `Task<bool>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an async method as the caller can await it.
The difference  with using 
`public async Task<bool> pushToDBAsync(....)` 
 
is that you give the caller the capability to decide how to handle the Task. Doing in that way may also help avoiding some pitfalls as mentioned in this blogpost: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Long story short: Labeling such a method with Async communicates the caller that it can be awaited and makes it easier to interact with your code.

Comment: No, `async` does nothing special for the caller. It's entirely an *implementation* detail of the method (that happens to appear in a place that makes it look like part of the signature). This is why you *cannot mark interface methods as async*.

Comment: As for "it is right to label such a method as an async method", that's primarily based on opinion, which I suspect this question really is. (I agree with that opinion, however, but that's besides the point

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen you are right about the opinion. Put the my argument that leads to that opinion to the answer.